# Enqueue scripts WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scripting

I've been trying to enqueue my scripts into a WordPress theme but none of them seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
// enqueue scripts
function add_scripts(){
// Load jQuery
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

// Your Scripts
wp_register_script('migrate', get_bloginfo('url').'/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js');
wp_register_script('touchswipe',get_bloginfo('url').'/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js');
wp_register_script('carouFredsel', get_bloginfo('url').'/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js');
wp_register_script('masonry',get_bloginfo('url').'/js/jquery.masonry.min.js');
wp_register_script('infinitescroll', get_bloginfo('url').'/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js');
wp_register_script('cycle',get_bloginfo('url').'/js/jquery.cycle.lite.js');
wp_register_script('phnx', get_bloginfo('url').'/js/phnx.js');
wp_enqueue_script('migrate');
wp_enqueue_script('touchswipe');
wp_enqueue_script('carouFredsel');
wp_enqueue_script('masonry');
wp_enqueue_script('infinitescroll');
wp_enqueue_script('cycle');
wp_enqueue_script('phnx');
}

add_action('init','add_scripts');
```

Comment: Please be more precise about your problem. "I don't understand." won't do it.

Answer (score 2):

If the scripts you are trying to enqueue are in your theme directory, you shouldn't be using `get_bloginfo('url')` to fetch the URL. You should be using `get_template_directory_uri()` or, if it's a child theme, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

```
wp_register_script('phnx', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/phnx.js');
```

Also, use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action instead of `init`.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_scripts');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function theme_styles() 
{
    /** @Styles */  
wp_enqueue_style('fonts','//cloud.typography.com/xx/css/fonts.css',array(),null,false);
wp_enqueue_style('script_name','path_to_css',array(),null,false);


    /** @Scripts */
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js',array(),null,true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'script_name', 'path_to_script',array(),null,true);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
```

Do not forget to put wp_head(); on header and wp_footer(); on footer

Comment: Hi, where would i put the head and footer comments? Ive copied my whole code below and its still not working. If you could point out what ive done wrong id be very grateful:

Comment: <?php

function theme_styles() 
{
    /** styles/
wp_enqueue_style('fonts','//cloud.typography.com/xx/css/fonts.css',array(),null,false);
wp_enqueue_style('script_name','path_to_css',array(),null,false);


    /** @Scripts */
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js',array(),null,true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'script_name', 'js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js',array(),null,true);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );

Comment: / favicon
function blog_favicon() {
echo '<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'http://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/favicon.ico" />';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'blog_favicon');

// remove Wordpress version number
function wpbeginner_remove_version() {
return '';
}
add_filter('the_generator', 'wpbeginner_remove_version');

Comment: //hook the administrative header output
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_logo');
function my_custom_logo() {
echo '
<style type="text/css">
#header-logo { background-image: url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/custom-logo.gif) !important; }
</style>
';
}

// footer Wordpress admin panel
function remove_footer_admin () {
echo 'Hand Crafted and Made with <i class="fa fa-heart" style="color:#e9643a"></i> by <a href="http://phnx.digital" target="blank">PHNX</a>';
}
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'remove_footer_admin');

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because none of the scripts or stylesheets work when i enqueue them